# 500: Internal Error in wordpress When using short code of gravityforms Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, gravity-forms-plugin

I am new in WordPress and I am using gravity forms plugin to create the

form But I am using the short code into the page and run the page on the browser

It is giving error

```
500: Internal Error
```

Actually I used so many time Gravity form Plugin I  work fine But Today I get

Error 500: Internal Error.

Comment: Check your error logs for details. Without that, who knows. The error logs will help you track down what the issue might be.

Comment: Have you double-checked that you had the correct `shortcode`?

Comment: @Poiz Actually this shotcode working before some days But now it is not showing form

Comment: Perhaps there was an update? Did you work on core files... i mean the plugin files?

Comment: no I am not working in core file

Comment: Then open `wp_config.php`. Then locate the entry: `define('WP_DEBUG',              false);` Change it to: `define('WP_DEBUG',              true); This would help in tracking down the error. This basically turns on Error-Reporting.